# Two ways to remove duplicates from a list

Tags: python, comparative-review

The question is - Write a program to remove the duplicates in a list

Here's how I did it-

```
numbers = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 7]
for i in numbers:
    while numbers.count(i) > 1:
        numbers.pop(numbers.index(i))
print(numbers)
```

Here's how the teacher in the youtube video did it-

```
numbers = [2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6]
uniques = []
for number in numbers:
    if number not in uniques:
        uniques.append(number)
print(uniques)
```

I know both the programs are objectively different in terms of how they do the task and the second program will I reckon consume more memory to create the new list however given the question which is the better approach and for what reasons?

Comment: Too short for an answer, so: `numbers = list(set(numbers))`

Comment: If you don't care about the order then just using `set(numbers)` will do the job

Comment: @FoundABetterNamd    OMG! Was it Mosh Hamedani’s tutorial? I watched the same one!

Comment: yup :) @fartgeek

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The teacher is obviously using a better way. Check/read more about time complexity for lists in python [here (python wiki)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list).

In your case, you are going for a time complexity:

- \$ O(n) \$ for iteration
- \$ O(n) \$ for `.count()`
- \$ O(n) \$ for intermediate pop
- \$ O(n) \$ for `.index`

for a final (worst case) time: \$ O(n^2) \$ (see explanation [in comments from superb rain](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251523/two-ways-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list/251524?noredirect=1#comment495269_251524)).

In case of the tutorial:

- \$ O(n) \$ for iteration
- \$ O(k) \$ for `not in` check (using \$ k \$ since the list is different now.
- \$ O(1) \$ for append

generating a worst case performance of \$ O(n \cdot k) \$.

---

A more efficient solution, disregarding the order of elements would be the call:

```
uniques = list(set(numbers))
```

as suggested in comments. This would have \$ O(n) \$ time.

Comment: If you do care about the order, you can still use a `set`, at the cost of O(k) additional memory, by keeping an additional `seen` set around.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Theirs is O(n^2), not just O(n^3).

Comment: Improvement on `uniques = list(set(numbers))` would be `uniques = list(dict.fromkeys(numbers))`; on modern Python (CPython/PyPy 3.6+, all Python 3.7+) `dict`s are insertion ordered, so the unique elements will remain in order of first appearance in the input, where `set` would apply a quasi-randomized order.

Comment: @superbrain "worst case" being all the numbers are the same. the outer loop would run once, but the while loop and pop+index get n^3

Comment: @ShadowRanger there was recently another post on code review, where it was seen that dict allocation takes a lot longer

Comment: @hjpotter92: Longer sure (`set` and `dict` are optimized for different use cases, `dict` has to have an unused value store `set` avoids, and certain resizing operations on `dict`s are more expensive due to variable width elements in the key array). But a *lot* longer? Depends on your idea of "a lot" I guess. In local tests, it looks like the worst case scenario has `list(dict.fromkeys(someiterable))` take twice as long as `list(set(someiterable))` (50-100% longer was typical). So sure, it's slower to use `dict.fromkeys`, but it's also the simplest way to preserve order to match OP's code.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I have no idea why you think they take n^3. They don't. Only n^2. In that "worst case", you have n count, n-1 index and n-1 pop, each of which takes time O(n). So ~3n\*O(n) = O(n^2).

Comment: @hjpotter92 Actually that's a best case. Someone sadly deleted the explanation I posted earlier, but here's a [benchmark](https://repl.it/repls/QuizzicalMeagerRectangle#main.py) now.

Comment: @superbrain updated my post above. not sure why i multiplied for `.pop` and `.index`

Comment: @ShadowRanger https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/250682/12240

Comment: @hjpotter92: Yeah, the conditions there are significantly different (implementation as Python code, not built-ins, where the Python bytecode differs a lot more, and `defaultdict(bool)` adds extra overhead to the addition of every new key). And in that solution, order is irrelevant, so `dict` doesn't provide any benefits "for free". Both conditions don't apply here; the incremental overhead for `dict.fromkeys` is less (though still non-zero) and preserving order is a meaningful benefit that `set` doesn't provide.

Comment: Both the teacher's and the student's codes are O(n^2). The teacher's code could easily be improved to O(n) by replacing the list `unique` by a python `set`. I wouldn't say the teacher's code is "obviously a better way" when they both have approximately the same complexity.

Comment: @Stef https://tinyurl.com/codereview-251523 check the timings, hence _obviously_.

Comment: @hjpotter92 The example you gave contains only duplicates of a single number. Nice way to choose an example so the numbers tell what you want them to tell!

Answer (score 9):

Your teacher's approach is better than yours, the main reason is the one noted in [the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251524/98493) by @hjpotter92.

However, their approach can be optimized even more. Note that there is the \$O(k)\$ check from `not in`. This is because when you check if an element is `in` a list, it goes through the whole list and tries to find it.

A `set` on the other hand stores elements via their hashes, giving you \$O(1)\$ `in` performance.

If you don't care about the order of elements, you can just pass the input directly to `set`:

```
numbers = [2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6]
uniques = list(set(numbers))
```

If you do, however, care about maintaining the order of elements (and always using the position of where the element *first* appeared), you have to fill both a `list` and a `set`:

```
uniques = []
seen = set()
for number in numbers:
    if number not in seen:
        uniques.append(number)
        seen.add(number)
print(uniques)
```

There are two caveats here, though:

- This takes additional memory, specifically \$O(k)\$, where \$k\$ is the number of unique elements.
- This only works if all elements of the input list are "hashable". This basically boils down to them being not mutable, i.e. you can't use it with a list of lists or dicts. Numbers and strings are perfectly fine, though.

Another thing you will probably learn about, if you haven't already, are functions. They allow you to encapsulate some functionality in one place, give it a name and reuse it:

```
def unique(x):
    uniques = []
    seen = set()
    for number in numbers:
        if number not in seen:
            uniques.append(number)
            seen.add(number)
    return uniques

numbers = [2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6]
print(unique (numbers))
```

Actually, there are two more reasons why your teacher's solution is better:

- You mutate the input list when you do `pop`. This means that you would have to make a copy if you need the original list afterwards.
- Your teacher's code works as long as `numbers` is iterable, i.e. you can do `for x in numbers`. Your code relies on less universal methods like `pop`, `count` and `index` which are not implemented by all data structures. Being able to be iterated over is very common, though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: It appears the two variables `seen` and `uniques` play the exact same role. You could simplify the code further: `uniques = list(set(numbers))`.

Comment: @Stef They do not. `uniques` is the output, which preserves the input order because it is a `list`. `seen` provides fast `in` comparisons, but no order information, since it is a `set`. Your approach is perfectly fine if the order does not matter (I forgot to add that as a note in my answer, though!).

Comment: Oops, you're right.

Answer (score 5):

`numbers.pop(numbers.index(i))` is equivalent to `numbers.remove(i)`.

Given that your example lists are sorted and that your solution would fail for example `[1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]` (which it turns into `[3, 1, 3, 2]`, not removing the duplicate `3`), I'm going to assume that the input being sorted is part of the task specification. In which case that should be taken advantage of. Neither of the two solutions does.

The teacher's can take advantage of it simply by checking `if number not in uniques[-1:]` instead of `if number not in uniques:`. Then it's O(n) instead of O(n^2) time.

An alternative with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
unique = [k for k, _ in groupby(numbers)]
```

Or in-place with just a counter of the unique values so far:

```
u = 0
for x in numbers:
    if u == 0 or x > numbers[u - 1]:
        numbers[u] = x
        u += 1
del numbers[u:]
```

Both take O(n) time. The latter is O(1) space if the final deletion doesn't reallocate or reallocates in place.

Comment: `not in uniques [-1:]` is equivalent to `!= uniques [-1]`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 No, the latter would crash with an IndexError, as `uniques` starts empty.